# More problems with data types

Tags: java, arrays, types

had some great help earlier with my class, which now compiles well, but getting an error in the sample demo the teacher wrote when trying to compile! I've narrowed down the error and why it could be happening, and tried half a dozen fixes but they just seem to create additional errors.

I've now got it down to only one error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[].

I get that the issue now has to be between how my class is working with my method, but as said, as a brand newbie at this, I just can't figure out how to fix it. Any point in the right direction will likely save me hours of stupidity! Is it because I'm not ssoting the array correctly in my class?

**My class (which compiles fine):**

```
public class DriverExam {
private char[] rightAnswers = { 'b', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 
'c', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'a' }; //Answers 
to test.
char[] Answers; //Student answer input.
int[] missed = {}; //Array for missed questions.
int correct = 0; //Create variable and initialise to 0.
int qMissed = 0; //Create variable and initialise to 0.

/** 
Constructor that accepts array of answers and copies to the answers array 

field.
@parem ans The array of student driver answers */


public DriverExam(char[] ans)
{
Answers = ans;
}

/**
An int array containing the question numbers of those questions that the 
student missed.
*/

public int questionsMissed() 

{
for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) //Ask program to step through 
each element in array answers.
    {
    if (Answers[index] == 0){
        return index + 1;}
    }
        return 0;//If nothing works



 }


public int qMissed() 
{
for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) //Ask program to step through 
each element in array answers.
    {
    if (Answers[index] == 0){
        return index++;} //count all missed questions.
        }
        return 0;
}


/**
A method that returns the total number of correctly answered questions.
@return Returns the number of correctly answered questions.
*/


public int totalCorrect()
{
for (int index = 0; index < Answers.length; index++)
{
if (Answers[index] == rightAnswers[index]) 
correct++;
}
return correct;
}


/**
A method that returns the total number of incorrectly answered questions.
@return Returns the number of incorrect answers.
*/


public int totalIncorrect()
{
    int incorrect = (rightAnswers.length - (totalCorrect() + qMissed));
    return incorrect;
}

/**
A method that returns true if the student passed the exam, or false if 
the student failed.
*/


public boolean passed()
{
    if(totalCorrect() >= 10); return true;
}


}
```

**The demo - which shows the incomparable error at line 43:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DriverExamDemo
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  String input;                             // To hold keyboard input
  final int NUM_ANSWERS = 20;               // Number of answers
  char[] answers = new char[NUM_ANSWERS];   // Array to hold answers
  int[] missedQuestions;                    // Array to hold missed  
  questions

  // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  // Get the user's answers to the questions.
  System.out.println("Enter your answers to the " +
                     "exam questions."); 
  for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)
  {
     System.out.print("Question " + (i + 1) + ": ");
     input = keyboard.nextLine();
     answers[i] = input.charAt(0);

     // Validate the answer.
     while (!valid(answers[i]))
     {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Valid answers are " +
                           "a, b, c, or d.");
        System.out.print("Question " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        answers[i] = input.charAt(0);
     }
  }

  // Create a DriverExam object.
  DriverExam exam = new DriverExam(answers);

  // Get an array of the missed question numbers.
  missedQuestions = exam.questionsMissed();

  // Display a report.
  System.out.println("Correct answers: " + exam.totalCorrect());
  System.out.println("Incorrect answers: " + exam.totalIncorrect());

  if (exam.passed())
     System.out.println("You passed the exam.");
  else
     System.out.println("You failed the exam.");

  if (missedQuestions != null)
  {
     System.out.println("You missed the following questions:");
     for (int i = 0; i < missedQuestions.length; i++)
        System.out.print(missedQuestions[i] + " ");
  }
  System.out.println(" ");

 }

 /**
  The valid method validates a character as an
  answer for the test.
  @param c The character to validate.
  @return true if the argument is a, b, c, or d.
          false otherwise.
*/

public static boolean valid(char c)
{
  boolean status;

  if (c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == 'd')
     status = true;
  else
     status = false;

  return status;
  }
}
```

I'll keep going over and over it, but any help would be appreciated.

N

Comment: Even if you are a newbie, can't you imagine that it is important to know the location where the compiler error is flagged?

Comment: Side note: start small: put a few lines of code (of which you think: this should compile) into your editor. Run the compiler. Fix bugs, if there are any. Add more code. Run the compiler. It doesn't make sense to create "huge" classes; that don't compile; to then turn to stack overflow again and again. The other thing: learn to **read** the compiler errors. Usually, they tell you **all** the things you need to know: line number, type of problem, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are unable to modify the demo itself, you must then change the `public int questionsMissed()` method in `DriverExam`.

The demo code:

```
System.out.println("You missed the following questions:");
for (int i = 0; i < missedQuestions.length; i++)
    System.out.print(missedQuestions[i] + " ");
```

You are expected to return an array of integers where each element in the array is a question number.

Your code:

```
public int questionsMissed() 
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) // Ask program to step through each element in array answers.
    {
        if (Answers[index] == 0){
            return index + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0; //If nothing works
}
```

As it stands, you return a single integer of index + 1 if the answer is 0. What you instead want to do is to store all the indices in an array. And then return the array at the very end of the for loop.

Note that array size cannot change once you allocate it. So an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
 missedQuestions = exam.questionsMissed();
```

exam.questionsMissed() returns integer where you are assigning to  integer array of missedQuestions.  Because of this you are getting the incompatible type error.

Modify the questionMissed method as below

```
    public int questionsMissed(int index) 
    {    
if (Answers[index] == 0){
    return index + 1;}
else
    return 0;//If nothing works
    }
```

and the below line

```
missedQuestions = exam.questionsMissed();
```

as follows

```
    int increment=0;
    for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
         int checkvalue=exam.questionsMissed(index);
         if(checkvalue!=0){
          missedQuestion[increment]=checkvalue
          increment++;
         }
    }
```

and check the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Mohan - I understood this was the reason, but I'm just not sure if I change the class or demo to fix it - I tried both and just got more errors.

Comment: Added the modified the code above hope it might helps you. It is an un tested code but hope you understand the logic behind the code modification.

Comment: Thanks so much Mohan, I tried this and had to play around with a few things but seems to work great. My concern is that my teacher wriote the demo and my class should work for it without having to change the demo (I'm assuming) - is there something I can do with my class that will make the demo work without having to change the demo? Or is the issue an intrinsic problem with the demo also?

Comment: If your program works for all kind of inputs then no worry for your teacher demo. If my answer solved your  problem then please accept the answer so that this problem will not show in unanswered section.

Comment: Thanks Mohan, unfortunately it doesn't quite fix the problem as the class should work for the demo without need to change the demo -- unless the teacher has made a mistake, which I'm guessing is unlikely. Thanks for your help though, it's certainly got me thinking!